# Proof that every subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ is generated by multiples of a basis from $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request, proof-explanation, alternative-proof

I am currently trying to understand why for a subgroup $g\subset \mathbb{Z}^n$ there is a basis of this subgroup $b_1, \dots, b_i$, such that the $b_j$ are multiples of a basis in $\mathbb{Z}^n$.

From an "experimental" standpoint this is clear - if I try some subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}^n$ I can find the corresponding basis pretty easy. E.g. $\langle (2,2,0), (0,0,4)\rangle$ is a subgroup that is generated by $(2,2,0)$ and $(0,0,4)$ and who's generators are multiples from elements from the basis $\{(1,1,0), (0,0,1), (1,0,0)\}$. But how do I proof that I can always find such a basis?

I was told that to proof this I can use that it is equivalent to the fact that every matrix over $\mathbb{Z}$ can be converted into Smith Normal Form. I do not understand how these statements are equivalent.

Is there a naive way (without deeper theory) to understand this connection or does it lie deeper? Do you know a proof that does not use the smith normal form? Is there a good source where the statement is proved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a property of principal ideal domains in general, much like the existence of the Smith normal form itself.

To see how it works over $ \mathbf Z $ in particular, imagine you're given a subgroup $ H \subset \mathbf Z^n $. The first coordinates of the elements of $ H $ form an ideal of $ \mathbf Z $, which is principally generated by some $ c $, say. It follows that there exists some element $ x \in H $ of the form $ x = (c, x_2, \ldots, x_n) $, and that you can write any element $ y \in H $ in the form $ y = qx + (0, z_2, \ldots, z_n) $. Iterate the procedure on $ (0, z_2, \ldots, z_n) $ by induction and you end up with a basis for $ H $ that has size at most $ n $.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see how this leads to a basis for $H$. But I do not see why the basis-element $x$ is now a multiple of a basis for $\mathbb{Z}^n$, or how to generate a basis who's elements are such multiples.

Comment: @Guenterino Your claim is false in general - for instance, the subgroup of $ \mathbf Z^2 $ generated by $ (1, 1) $ clearly admits no such basis. What you can say using the Smith normal form is every subgroup $ H \subset \mathbf Z^n $ is *isomorphic to* a subgroup admitting such a basis of multiples, but that already follows from the argument I gave.

Comment: But in this case there is a basis $\{ (1,1), (1,0) \}$ of $\mathbb{Z}^2$, where the subgroup is generated by $(1,1)$, which is a multiple of the basis-element $(1,1)$.

Anyway what you said - that it is isomorphic to such a subgroup is all I need - would you mind to explain to me why it follows from the argument you gave? Thank you for your answers!

Comment: @Guenterino All free modules of the same rank are isomorphic..? I don't understand what your difficulty is with the answer.

Comment: Ah nice ok, I missed this!